# AOP with Spring Boot Advice Not Triggering

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, aop

Using: Spring Boot :: (v1.2.8.RELEASE)

I have set up a Spring Boot application with the aop starter in build.gradle

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
```

I have checked and I am getting the dependencies:

```
|    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
```

This is the AspectConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

I have placed the Configuration class at the base of the application hierarchy, so that the component scanning just covers the whole application. This is all prototype code,but it will eventually form part of a starter module, the the ability to scan all areas would be helpful.

Now I have defined an annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface AutowiredRestTemplate {
    String name();
    String methodUrl();
}
```

And have a test method:

```
@Component(value = "testGateway")
public class TestGatewayImpl implements TestGateway {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestGatewayImpl.class);

    AuspostRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @AutowiredRestTemplate(name = "locations", methodUrl = "/fishing")
    public Response doWork() {
        LOG.debug("Got into gateway with restTemplate {}", restTemplate);
        return restTemplate.getForObject(Response.class);
    }
}
```

and now the advice:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AutowiredRestTemplateAspect {

    @Autowired
    Map<String, AuspostRestTemplate> restTemplateMap;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod(){}

    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(autowiredRestTemplate)")
    public Object inAnyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, AutowiredRestTemplate autowiredRestTemplate) throws Throwable{

        AuspostRestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateMap.get(autowiredRestTemplate.name());
        restTemplate.setMethodUrl(autowiredRestTemplate.methodUrl());
            pjp.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredField("restTemplate").set(pjp.getTarget(),restTemplate);
        return pjp.proceed();

    }
}
```

The issue is that the Advice never gets triggered when the `doWork()` method is run. It even looks as though from the logs that the pointcut doesn't even get set up. Can anyone see what's wrong here?

**EDIT:** I have added the Config and the Retention and Target annotations for the Annotation that I want to use (above in this question).
**EDIT2:** Changed the ComponentScan on the Configuration class as the other thing was complicated and didn't work anyway.

Comment: Is that your whole annotation?

Comment: Also you are aware that what you are doing is potentially dangerous? One template could overwrite the other on multiple requests.

Comment: oh, i guess i should have included all the Config that sets up the map of requestTemplates. Nothing is overwritten, just differant requestTemplates are chosen from the map (loaded up at application start). I just didn't include all that stuff, because it didn't seem relevant to the question

Comment: Still there is a single instance for a certain name. Now if you have multiple threads needing that single instance, you are changing one that is in use already... It isn't relevant just wanted to point that out. As mentioned in my first comment is that your whole annotation and can you also add which version of Spring Boot you are using.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2.8. Java 8. Yes it was the whole annotation. I was under the impression that Runtime was the default RetentionPolicy and the Target is everything by default. I did try setting both (including @Target({ElementType.METHOD}), but it didn't make any difference. So, yes, that's the whole annotation.

Comment: Ah so returning to the single instance, I am attempting to set the RestTemplate member of the invoker to the named member - yes, I see the issue. If i ever get the pointcut to fire off, i'll look for a way to deal with that without resorting to synchronisation.

Comment: Show us the config used for enabling AOP.

Comment: Default is CLASS not RUNTIME so you really have to add at least that. You also have to make sure that the aspect is in a package that is scanned at startup, else your aspect won't work.

Comment: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` implies `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false)`. In your case, the annotation is on the implementation method, whereas the AspectJ proxy will be on the interface method (since `TestGatewayImpl` implements `TestGateway`). You therefore need to set `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`, which will force AspectJ to proxy the implementation class instead of the interface. Alternatively, you can move the annotation to the interface method.

Comment: I have the same problem now, with Spring Boot 1.3.5. @MichaelCoxon - have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try putting `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` on your configuration class?

Comment: yes, I did. I have just added the Config class to the question, since it appears to be pretty relevant.

Comment: This solved my problem - thank you Jakub!